# Jquery UI SELECTABLE, how to select one item only?

Tags: jquery-ui, selectable

is there any way to define that, only one item can be selected with jquery.selectable widget?

Or i've to inmplement a workarround capturing events and manipulating by my self what happens?

Comment: Do you want to deselect a previously-selected item? Or prevent the selection of a second item?

Comment: what i pretend is to get only one item selected like  a "dropdown behavior" or a radiobutton.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#myList li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: `selected` should be `ui-selected`

Comment: Also, this doesn't handle the mouse select case.

Answer (score 25):

I expanded on Nirmal's answer to limit the mouse select case.  Also, I feel that it is cleaner to use the `selected` option rather than a completely separate event handler.

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) { 
        $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");           
    }                   
});
```

There is one minor problem remaining.  When selecting multiple items with the mouse the last item will always be selected.  This is because the function passed into the `selected` option is run for each selected item, which I assume goes in item order.  Ideally the item that your mouse cursor lands at would be selected.  I didn't fix this because I mainly just wanted a multiple selection constraint when using the mouse.

Comment: +1 This works great. (In my particular case the items do not have descendants.)

Comment: To disable multiple items getting caught in the lasso:  
    
`$("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) { 
        $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");           
    },
    selecting: function(event, ui) { 
        $(ui.selecting).addClass("ui-selecting").siblings().removeClass("ui-selecting");           
    },
});`

Answer (score 8):

I improve mattblang's answer a little. Siblings can have also descendants, so more general answer is:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected").each(
            function(key,value){
                $(value).find('*').removeClass("ui-selected");
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: thats better... improved answered